# IOS-didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)”

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I try to get the longitude & latitude of the user current location, my code is simply this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    float latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    float longitude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"%f",latitude);
    NSLog(@"%f",longitude);
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}
```

I got always this error from the didFailWithError method :

```
didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

[image]

Comment: i reset network but still dont work. @derpoliuk

Comment: @Mr.Bond please check your location in simulator Debug>Location>Current Location

Comment: that's also not work.@bhavin ramani

Comment: @Mr.Bond have you set your current location in simulator or in xcode?

Comment: yes, i put LONDON in xcode, but still dont work.

Comment: @Mr.Bond when your app is running click on debug>location and london...then tell me what happened

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108169/discussion-between-bhavin-ramani-and-mr-bond).

Comment: are you add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription this key in .plist on your project ?  if you forgot then please add this key and value in .plist  NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription = Application would like to use your location

Comment: how to add this value and key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think,
you need to add following permission  in `.plist` in your project

`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and that value is `Application would like to use your location`

and second is , add `[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];` line in your code.

> this code in i added :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```